# Windows batch equivalent of "command" in linux bash

Tags: bash, batch

In linux bash there's a `command` command which can execute the "real" command even if you have a function name or a script filename that is named equal to that command.

```
function ping(){
    echo do nothing
}
command ping
```

will still work.

In windows batch, I have a file `ping.cmd` which goes into loop if I run `ping` inside of it.

What's the equivalent of `command` in windows batch?

Comment: Updated my answer as I had completely forgotten about the possible fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1: None, because **Windows batch doesn't even *have* functions like bash does.** It only has subroutines that use a different syntax than regular commands – `ping` vs `call :ping` – so there's no need for an override.

If you read the documentation more closely, `command` only skips aliases and functions, but does nothing about scripts in $PATH. **In both shells**, if you override using a real script file, **it's up to you to find the "real" command.**

Answer 2: To avoid the loop that you described, **you'll need to specify the full name** of "ping".

- With bash, that would mean calling `/bin/ping`, or perhaps looping over $PATH until you find it.
- On Windows, the same options exist; however, since your script is actually called `ping.bat` or `ping.cmd`, you can **run `ping.exe`** to avoid looping.